# XSLT: Can not find Java class exception

Tags: java, xslt, groovy

It works fine if remove reference to Java class from xslt.
**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="Client">
            <xsl:variable name="uid" select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
```

Groovy

```
import java.util.UUID

TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                  .newTransformer( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xslt ) ) )
                  .transform( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xmlAsString ) ),
                              new StreamResult( w ) )
```

**Exception**

```
ERROR:  'Cannot find class 'java:java.util.UUID'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
Caught: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with `xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID"` I got from one of the blog post. 
Updated it to `xmlns:uuid="java.util.UUID"` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be:

```
xmlns:uuid="java://java.util.UUID"
```